# Redmine2.6.5 に Backlogs をインストールするときの「You must set the default issue priority in redmine prior to installing backlogs」

Tags: redmine

AmazonEC2 の AmazonLinux 上に、Redmine2.6.5 をインストールしまして、Backlogs （http://www.redminebacklogs.net/）をインストールしようと、操作をしている最中の事です。

http://www.redminebacklogs.net/en/installation.html#

を見ながら操作して、

```
gem install holidays --version 1.0.3
gem install holidays
git clone git://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs.git
cd redmine_backlogs
git checkout v1.0.6
```

から始まり、

```
bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear
bundle exec rake tmp:sessions:clear
```

まで完了した後の操作です。
Redmine ルートディレクトリ上で、

```
bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install
```

または、production を指定した

```
bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install RAILS_ENV=production
```

どちらのパターン(bundle exec 有無も含め)においても、

```
# bundle exec rake redmine:backlogs:install
rake aborted!
You must set the default issue priority in redmine prior to installing backlogs
/var/lib/redmine/plugins/redmine_backlogs/lib/tasks/install.rake:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:backlogs:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

となっています。
正直に言いますと、「default issue」が何なのか、加えて、その設定方法について知識・情報が不足しており、解決に至っておりません。

そもそも Backlogs の対応してるバージョンも相当古いですし、さっさと捨てて新しいプラグインに走れという結論もやむなしとは考えていますが、使えるものなら使いたいという事もありますので、ご存知の方は知恵をお貸し頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己完結しました。
インストール操作上の「優先度」、つまりプラグインの適用優先度みたいなものがあると勝手に思い込んでいましたが、これは Redmine の チケット優先度のデフォルトの事だったのですね…。

管理者でログインして、チケット優先度を表示した後、正常にインストール操作を継続できました。